# Why is Google DNS resolving to a different server?

Tags: networking, dns

Im using google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) on 2 separate routers on two different networks.

When i go to [THIS](https://www.top10vpn.com/tools/what-is-my-dns-server/) website to check what DNS is being used, when connected to each network i get the following :

Network 1 :

- US    GOOGLE - Google LLC 74.125.43.197
- Plus some other google IPv6 addresses

Network 2 :

- US    GOOGLE - Google LLC 172.271.47.130
- US    GOOGLE - Google LLC 172.271.47.135
- Plus some other google IPv6 addresses

Any idea why its not displaying 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 ?

My thought was that possibly a request to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 which are general addresses, get routed to a more geographically local address (like a CDN) which are the addresses above, but thats only my theory. Is that correct or is there something else happening here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your
[link](https://www.top10vpn.com/tools/what-is-my-dns-server/)
has a good explanation for this:

> If you’ve changed device or router DNS settings to use a specific DNS server, for example a Google (8.8.8.8) or a Cloudflare (1.1.1.1) server, you may see a slightly different DNS address.
>
> This is because when you use an organization’s DNS server (e.g. 8.8.8.8), the server sends your requests onto other servers (with different IP addresses) in the company’s network to avoid server congestion.

So when then DNS request is sent to Google, it is diverted to some DNS
server in the Google network (there are many such), which is what you
see.

Note that the last two IPs that you got,
`172.271.47.130` and `172.271.47.135`, are not even accessible.